# How to send data from VC subview to VC superview

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a firstController and a secondController. When a cell is clicked in the firstController a numpad(= secondController) gets loaded in as subview. I want to connect the buttons of the numpad to the first collection so that i'm able to instantly show the number in a label on the firstController. The transaction of data should be immediate.

I can't connect the buttons to the first viewcontroller.
This is the first time I attempt to use this, so I might be looking at it the wrong way entirely. I used two different viewControllers to maintain overview in my storyboard.

Any suggestions on how to forward the data from a VC subview to superview?

[image: When collection cell is clicked the pickerview appears]

Comment: have you tried delegate concept to achieve this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you run the second view controller(`NumpadVC`) from the first you certainly have a reference to the `NumpadVC`.

A suitable solution is  to declare a protocol (outside any class)

```
protocol NumPadDelegate {
  didTapButton(button: UIButton)
}
```

and a delegate in `NumpadVC`

```
var delegate NumPadDelegate?
```

Every time a button is tapped call

```
delegate?.didTapButton(button)
```

and pass the reference to the current button.

---

In the first view controller add `NumPadDelegate` to the class declaration line  and just before the transition to `NumpadVC` set the delegate of `numpadVC` (assuming that's the name of the instance) to `self`.

```
numpadVC.delegate = self
```

Then implement

```
func didTapButton(button: UIButton) {}
```

to handle the button clicks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a delegate to pass data back to the firstcontroller.

On the numpad view create a delegate will be triggered when someone enters a number.

```
protocol NumpadDelegate {
    func numpadWasPressed(value:Int)
}
```

and a var on numpadvc that is the delegate

```
 var delegate: NumpadDelegate?
```

Your first vc then needs to implement the delegate and set itself as the delegate

```
 FirstVC: NumPadDelegate {

    func viewDidLoad() {
      self.numpadVC.delegate = self
    }
 }
```

On the method that is triggered when someone presses a number call your delegate method

```
self.delegate.?numpadWasPressed(numpadValue)
```

Then the firstviewcontroller will implement that delegate and when the numpad it pressed you can get the data from that method.

```
func numpadWasPressed(value:Int) {
   //get numpad value here

 }
```

Something like that